# Java Sockets listener

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, network-programming, queue

Would it be appropriate to use a thread to get objects received by a socket's InputStream and then add them to a ConcurrentLinkedQueue so that they can be accessed from the main thread without blocking at the poll-input loop?

```
private Queue<Packet> packetQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Packet>();
private ObjectInputStream fromServer; //this is the input stream of the server
public void startListening()
{
    Thread listeningThread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while(isConnected())    //check if the socket is connected to anything
            {
                try {
                    packetQueue.offer((Packet) fromServer.readObject());  //add packet to queue
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    listeningThread.start();  //start the thread 
}

public Packet getNextPacket()
{
    return packetQueue.poll();  //get the next packet in the queue
}
```

Comment: You need to catch `EOFException` and break out of the read loop when you get it, and all other `IOExceptions` except `SocketTimeoutException` are fatal as well. Your `join()` call won't work either: it will just try to join itself, which will just block forever, as the thread can't die while it's blocked in `join()`. I don't really see the point of your suggestion.

Comment: Its constantly reading from the server until the client disconnects IE: more than one Object is being received, an arbitrary number to be more precise

Comment: I can see what your code does, and I've already commented extensively on it. What I can't see is the point of your suggestion about the queue. And what is your definition of 'appropriate'? The question really isn't answerable without a statement of your requirements.

Comment: as a way of avoiding blocking the main thread with this loop, and allowing the main thread to access the next unread Object asynchronously.  I am asking if doing this is acceptable, or perhaps if there is a better way of doing this. asynchronously meaning at any arbitrary time.

Comment: But why? What else is the main thread going to do while there is nothing on the queue?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to do with this object that you'll use in main thread.

If need sometime to process it or if it'll be used many times than you can put it in a queue or in another class that will hold this object for you, but if the time you need to process it is low you and you don't need this object further after processing you don't really need to use a queue.

About using the ConcurrentQueue depends too, you need order? you need guarantee synchronism between the read and the write?

You can use Asynchronous socket too to handle many clients and process in the same thread or even getting the objects from them and throwing in a queue to further process.

But "be appropriate" is hard to answer because depends on what you need to do with this objects and how you'll handle it.

Comment: Objects need to be accessed in the order they are received and there is a noticeable amount of processing time per each Object.  and the synchronized queue is because I have a second thread that will be adding to the queue while the main thread will be accessing them.